# How do i find out if WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync was cancelled?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, xamarin.ios, webclient

How do i know if a call to WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync was cancelled?

My method call is like this:

```
WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(uri, filename);
```

The call is then cancelled elsewhere with:

```
webClient.CancelAsync();
```

When the await continues, how do i know if it was succesful or was cancelled?

Comment: Won't that throw an exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `await`, then an [`OperationCanceledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operationcanceledexception.aspx) object will be thrown if the object that you are awaiting on is canceled.

If the task is not canceled, execution will resume normally after the `await` point.

Comment: +1: Right, obviously! Somehow, I got my mind fixed on Task not await.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember well, you can simply inspect the `Task` object that you awaited for.

```
WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
var task = webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(uri, filename);
await task;
```

later, you can inspect it:

```
task.Status
task.IsCancelled
task.IsCompleted  -> task.Result
task.IsFaulted    -> task.Exception
```

[MSDN:Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424(v=vs.110).aspx)

...or just check **Jean Hominal's** excellent point on that topic (upon task failure, the **await** simply throws instead of continuing).

Comment: Thanks. I tried almost the same with Task task = await webClient.etc...
But the compiler complained about it returning null instead of task.

Answer (score 0):

As the `DownloadFileTaskAsync` method returns a Task you should be able to simply look at the `IsCancelled` property.

```
if (task.IsCancelled) {
     // Task was cancelled.
}
```

See this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx

> IsCancelled - Gets whether this Task instance has completed execution
>   due to being canceled.